# Events documentation for Craft 3

Tags: craft3, events

I've been looking for an Event Reference doc for Craft 3 just like what we had for Craft 2, but couldn't find one. The only events doc I found for Craft 3 is the plugin updating guide: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#events.

Did I miss anything? Appreciate if someone can post a link here.

Also, for Craft 2 events, we used to be able to do $event->params[$paramName] to get the params passed into the events, but I struggle to find a way to do similar things in Craft 3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a list of Event classes and the "Public Properties" that you can get or set:

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-events-assetevent.html

### An example of getting event data:

```
Event::on(
    Users::class,
    Users::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTIVATE_USER,
    function (UserEvent $event) {
        $userElement = $event->user;
    }
);
```

Class reference: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-events-userevent.html

### An example of setting event data:

```
Event::on(
    Fields::class,
    Fields::EVENT_REGISTER_FIELD_TYPES,
    function (RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
        $event->types[] = UserState::class;
    }
);
```

Class reference: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-events-registercomponenttypesevent.html

Answer (score 13):

Whilst Doug's answer is useful for knowing the ins and outs of a particular event once you've found it, actually finding which events are available in Craft 3 in the current docs is not straight-forward. After a bit of digging, you'll find that most events are part of Craft's **services** - so head to the [Class Reference](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/) and choose the most relevant service from the `craft/services` menu on the sidebar. The events available to each service are listed at the end of each one. For example:

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-users.html#events
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#events
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-fields.html#events
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-volumes.html#events

etc etc... (between Craft and Yii there are almost 3000 different events to choose from!).

---

### Edit to add...

Craft's docs now have a fantastic event code generator tool that helps to narrow down which event you need and provides the scaffolding for calling each one: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/events.html#event-code-generator